# nginx 301 permanent redirect

Tags: nginx

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how should I make a hole bunch of redirects (301) to Nginx. Maybe you can give me some help.

Basically I have a few hundred of url's like this one above:
http://www.website.com/product/intl/bg-BG/browserchoice/download.html?track=1871

And I need to redirect to:
http://www.website.com/home/download/download.php?prod=browser&track=1871

How should I do it? (*bg-BG from source is the single variable that changes)

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it peforms internal redirect in nginx:

```
rewrite ^/product/intl/.*/browserchoice/download.html$ /home/download/download.php?prod=browser&$args break;
```

But if you really want redirect (**this is not a good choice**) :

```
rewrite ^/product/intl/.*/browserchoice/download.html$ http://www.website.com/home/download/download.php?prod=browser&$args permanent;
```

I also suggest you to read official documentation here http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule